# SQL Server 2008R2 SSIS Package for deployment on SQL Server 2008(R1)

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I think I can probably guess that the answer to this question is going to be NO!

Here goes anyway... I have developed an SSIS package on my local development machine with SQL Server 2008R2 installed.

When I went to deploy on the production server the package failed with all sorts of errors. After digging around I discovered the production server is running SQL 2008 (not R2).

Question: is there a simple way (preferably some simple setting in the IDE) that will make my  package compatible?

**UPDATE:** This is the exact error I get when I try to execute the package on SQL Server(R1)

```
 Description: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ComponentVersionMismatchException:
 The version of component "ADO NET Destination" (79) is not compatible with 
 this version of the DataFlow.  [[The version or pipeline version or both for the
 specified component is higher than the current version.  This package was probab
 ly created on a new version of DTS or the component than is installed on the cur
 rent PC.]]
```

Comment: Are you certain the two are related? Off the cuff, I thought the only change they introduced in R2 wrt to SSIS was the ADO.NET destination or something like that. Otherwise, I've been developing using 2008 R2 BIDS packages and deploying to 2088 SP2 just fine

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i'll do a little more digging around!

Comment: Feel free to update with the actual errors, we're usually pretty good at figuring them out ;) There is an SSIS downgrader project on codeplex if you have need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems ADO NET destinations are the only incompatible things between 2008 and 2008R2. For a solution, see:
http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2010/05/13/moving-ssis-packages-with-ado-net-destinations-between-2008-r2-and-2008/

Comment: extremely helpfull link. In the article below you can have a tool which makes conversion easy when you have to run it multiple times. A great help!